# Changing of SuperTabItem by code

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbar, supertab

I have two SuperTabItems in a SuperTabControl. I want to change from SuperTabItem1 to SuperTabItem2 clicking a button.

I'm using DotNetBar components. The function of a SuperTabControl is the same as a TabControl in the normal objects of Visual Basic. But it looks like the code doesn't work the same for these Tab objects.

I tryed this and many other types of lines, but nothing:

```
SuperTabControl1.Select(stAsignar)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `SelectedTabIndex`? For example: `SuperTabControl1.SelectedTabIndex = TABINDEX` This information is found right in their documentation [**here**](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=393)

Comment: **I just tried but give me this error:** A value of type 'DevComponents.DotNetBar.SuperTabItem' can not be converted to 'Integer'.

Comment: Because it takes an index which is an integer data type, **not** a `TabItem`, did you read the link I gave you. You need to specify the index of the tab you want to select... Or create your own function pass the tabitem to it and search the tabs, once your tab is found return the index...

Comment: I don't want indexes, I want to _show_ the tab. But some how your link brings me to use this: SuperTabControl1.SelectedTab = stAssign '<<This works for me!

Comment: So, I mean Thanks @Zaggler!!